# How to install apktool on Win 10?

Tags: apktool

I have downloaded both apktool_2.1.1.jar & apktool_2.0.0rc4.jar from https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads and pasted it in C://Windows. Yet when I run apktool in cmd, it returns:

> C:\Users\arpit>apktool
>   'apktool' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 8):

->Download Windows wrapper script from here https://raw.githubusercontent.com/iBotPeaches/Apktool/master/scripts/windows/apktool.bat
(Right click, Save Link As apktool.bat)

->Download apktool-2 https://bitbucket.org/iBotPeaches/apktool/downloads
(find newest here)

->Rename downloaded jar to apktool.jar

->Move both files (apktool.jar & apktool.bat) to your System32 directory (Usually C:\Windows\system32)
If you do not have access to C:\Windows\system32, you may place the two files anywhere then add that directory to your Environment Variables System PATH variable.

->Try running apktool with admin previlages via command prompt

Answer (score 1):

Apktool is a tool for reverse engineering 3rd party, closed, binary Android apps. It can decode resources to nearly original form and rebuild them after making some modifications. You will find apktool indispensible if you want to extract resources (i.e. images from an Android application. Actually, the tool has no competitors at all!)

An online version of the apktool is available here: [www.javadecompilers.com/apktool](http://www.javadecompilers.com/apktool)

Comment: Is it safe/credible?